# Создание новой директории в корне проекта advanced

Tags: php, yii2, yii

Использую шаблон приложения advanced.

Хочу создать новую директорию в корне проекта и там описывать свою структуру. Вот как это выглядит у меня:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пытаюсь обратиться к классу SuperTest из backend, например.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Класс подключаю так:

```
use modules\user\modules\v1\backend\models\SuperTest;
```

В итоге получаю ошибку: `Class 'modules\user\modules\v1\backend\models\SuperTest' not found`

Как я понимаю, автолоадер не может загрузить этот класс.

Как мне сделать так, чтобы я смог нормально работать с новой директорией?

Answer (score 0):

Дочерние модули объявляются в свойстве `modules` родительских модулей. Например:

```
namespace backend\modules\user;

class User extends \yii\base\Module
{
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        $this->modules = [
            'v1' => [
                'class' => 'backend\modules\user\modules\v1\V1',
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

Правда ничего не могу сказать насчёт помещения туда целого приложения, не приходило как-то в голову